# Which data type has a better time and space complexity in pandas: pd.CategoricalDtype or enum.Enum?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, enums, time-complexity

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html), the categorical value is useful:

- If there are few different values for a given column
- If the lexical order differs from the logical order (e.g. "small", "big", "large")
- If you want to signal the category type to other Python libraries (e.g. matplotlib, seaborn)

The documentation states that converting string variables to categorical variables will save some memory. So the space complexity of the `categorical` type is better than other data types such as `str` or `enum.Enum` type.

Is the time complexity of the categorical type also better than other data types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time complexity is also better for the categorical type for sorting and filtering operations. In order to measure performance, create the data frames for the different data types. The following example will compare the `pd.CategoricalDtype` and `enum.Enum` type space and time complexity.

Define an ordered categorical data type. In this example, four categories are in the following order: "One" < "Two" < "Three" < "Four".

```
import pandas as pd

cat = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]
cat_type = pd.CategoricalDtype(categories=cat, ordered=True)
```

Define an Enum data type with the same ordering. The less-than operator is overridden for comparison.

```
from enum import Enum

class Unit(Enum):
    One = 1
    Two = 2
    Three = 3
    Four = 4

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.__class__ is not other.__class__:
            return NotImplemented
        return self.value < other.value
```

Generate one million records of `Unit` categories which are uniformly distributed.

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Unit": np.random.choice(cat, 1000000)})
```

Convert the `Unit` column to an enum and to a categorical data type.

```
enum_df = df.copy()
cat_df = df.copy()
enum_df["Unit"] = np.vectorize(lambda x: Unit[x])(enum_df["Unit"].values)
cat_df = cat_df.astype(pd.CategoricalDtype(categories=cat, ordered=True))
```

The memory usage can be displayed by the `memory_usage` function. The enum data frame memory usage is 8000000 bytes and the category data frame memory usage is 1000204 bytes. It means that the category type is about 8x less memory usage than the enum type at 1 million records.

```
print("Enum df memory usage: ", enum_df.memory_usage())
print("Categorical df memory usage: ", cat_df.memory_usage())
```

The sorting speed is exceedingly faster (~400x) for the categorical type than the enum type. The filtering speed is significantly faster (~20x) for the categorical type. It is tested on Windows 10 with Python 3.11.2 version. Here are some execution samples:

|  | sorting category type | sorting enum type | filtering category type | filtering enum type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.026s | 12.848s | 0.006s | 0.163s |
| 2 | 0.025s | 10.46s | 0.003s | 0.093s |
| 3 | 0.031s | 10.61s | 0.006s | 0.092s |
| 4 | 0.035s | 11.35s | 0.003s | 0.083s |
| 5 | 0.025s | 10.89s | 0.006s | 0.090s |
| **Average** | 0.0284s | 11.2316s | 0.0048s | 0.1042s |

The code for measuring the sorting time complexity:

```
import time

t0 = time.time()
cat_df.Unit.sort_values()
t1 = time.time()

total1 = t1-t0
print(total1, ' seconds')

t0 = time.time()
enum_df.Unit.sort_values()
t1 = time.time()

total2 = t1-t0
print(total2, ' seconds')
```

The code for measuring the filtering time complexity:

```
t0 = time.time()
cat_df[cat_df.Unit == 'One']
t1 = time.time()

total1 = t1-t0
print(total1, ' seconds')

t0 = time.time()
enum_df[enum_df.Unit == Unit.One]
t1 = time.time()

total2 = t1-t0
print(total2, ' seconds')
```